# Can you have 3 separate Shared Document web parts on one site?

Tags: web-part

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm currently creating a site, I want to be able to upload documents so I have added 3 web parts for shared documents, however if I upload something to one it adds it to all three. Is there a way to make each one independent so the documents uploaded only gets added to that specific Webpart on that site page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each webpart acts as a pointer to a list or library on your site, specifically in your case, a Document Library. What's happening is that you're adding three webparts pointing to the same Document Library, so when you add a document to the library, it's displaying in all three webparts. If you want three separate Document Libraries, click on the "Site Contents" link, usually at the bottom of the left-side navigation bar or in the 'gear' menu at the top right of the page, and you should see an option to 'Add an app' or something similar. From there you can create additional Document Libraries.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can solve problem

1. Using View: you can also create 3 different view for same document library and attached different view to each web part. while creating view please apply filter according to your business logic.
2. Create Different Document library, in your case you have to create 2 more document library.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding one document library as 3 webparts. you have to create 2 more document libraries and place it as 3 webparts.